# Screen capture program with upload feature to image sharing sites

Tags: screen-capture

*The title pretty much explains it ...*

Anyone knows of any screen capture programs which offer a feature to upload the result to imageshack, or some similar site, and gives an URL, so it can be quickly used when composing webpages, or answering questions on SO/SU ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best, hands-down, is [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/).

Comment: +1 for the best and easiest to use screen capture program

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/)?

Comment: No, but BlueRaja has ;-)

Comment: +1 for the effort, but BlueRaja did beat you in the photofinish ;-) Very nice program, btw.

Answer (score 1):

[Aviary.com](http://aviary.com/) allows you to do screen capture. You can save the files to your clipboard, desktop, **or online**.

For web stuff, there's no software to install. You capture any webpage by adding Aviary.com/ to the beginning of the URL.

> To capture `http://google.com` you type `Aviary.com/http://google.com`

Or access the tools via their website or one of their browser extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a new one-click [easy image uploader](http://www.zabkat.com/blog/27Dec09-image-uploader.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Jing, but [ZScreen](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/) gives you many upload options.  It is highly configurable.  It's FOSS.

[image: Zscreen config]