# From image on my computer to URL in my clipboard

Tags: windows-7, images, clipboard, upload, online-storage

I use [tinypic](http://www.tinypic.com/) for hosting images for forum posts, online articles, etc etc, as I'm sure many other people do too.

From an image on my computer's desktop to having the URL in my clipboard after it has been uploaded seems to be way longer than it could be.

1. Open browser
2. Navigate to image hosting website
3. Click upload
4. Navigate to image on desktop
5. Click OK
6. Copy URL to clipboard

Instead, I want to simply be able to do this:

1. Right-click image on desktop
2. Click a magic option in the menu, such as *'Upload and copy URL to the clipboard'*

Is there a tool that has this functionality?

I am using Windows 7 and freeware would be ideal.  Although I like tinypic, the tool can relate to any hosting service.  I am more interested in the tool to do this, not the hosting company itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a tool that has this
>   functionality?

There sure is ...

**[Tinypic/Imageshack Uploader](http://eden.fm/tinypic-uploader/)**

> With this little tool you can very
>   easily upload pictures to
>   www.tinypic.com, www.imageshack.us and
>   www.messyshare.com without having to
>   go through their website. You can
>   enable shell link integration and
>   simply Right-click the file and select
>   “Send to
>   TinyPic/Imageshack/MessyShare“ or drag
>   the file to the app. window and it
>   will automatically start uploading.

[image]

Features:

- Send multiple files in a queue
- Crop an area of the screen
- Send existing files via context-menu (32-bit only), selecting them from a dialog, or dragging them to the application window
- Capture the active window when you press F11
- Select a window from currently running applications via Aero live thumbs (Vista and W7 only)
- Send your clipboard contents (image)
- Send to either Tinypic, Imageshack or Messyshare, and get the direct link copied to your clipboard automatically
- Auto-resize pictures and/or lower quality automatically if file exceeds a given size, to speed-up uploads on slow connections (like non-Japanese)
- Store captures from cropping or paste etc
- Supports multiple monitors in any configurations (spanned horz/vertically etc)
- Works in Linux via wine libraries
- .net framework is NOT required
- Supports specific Windows 7 features (taskbar progress)
- Store a log with comments and its link about every upload

*Tinypic/Imageshack Uploader is freeware.*

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking of capturing screenshots for the purpose of posting to online forums like this one, in answers and such ... you may be interested in an older question of mine that deals with the subject:

> [Screen capture program with upload feature to image sharing sites](https://superuser.com/questions/92722/screen-capture-program-with-upload-feature-to-image-sharing-sites)

Comment: It's more for images I already have on my PC - not for new screenshots.  I've amassed a bunch of them over the years creating articles locally.  Now I find they're needed online, it's just a pain doing it how I'm doing it.  Thanks for the heads up on your question though, Jing (accepted answer) is kinda cool, albeit not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

DropBox's client application allows one to do this. Anything placed in your "Public" folder can be right-click->Copy URL to clipboard-ed.

Comment: Mmmmmmmmmm interesting.  That's something I never thought about, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The free tool [Click.to](http://www.clicktoapp.com/) has similiar functionality, helping to upload pictures to some websites.

Here is an article about Click.to:

> http://techcrunch.com/2011/07/08/from-your-clipboard-to-just-about-anywhere-sharing-files-in-one-click-to/

Answer (score 0):

Old question, I know. But I was unsatisfied with the existing solutions. Either they have to much features like an editor, aren't portable, don't support Imgur.com or aren't "one-click" solutions.

So I decided to write my own app and share it with the superuser community

---

## [Send to Imgur](https://github.com/ShinyId3Tagger/Sendto-Imgur)

[image]
[image]

> - Free, portable, small
> - One-click solution via *send to* context menu
> - Imgur URL is copied to clipboard
> - No GUI or any other unneeded stuff
> - Source code on GitHub